# How do I use DASH instead of HLS in Cloudflare video streaming?

Tags: http-live-streaming, cloudflare, mpeg-dash

I'm using Cloudflare as the video streaming provider for a project. I'm trying to pre-fetch multiple videos on a mobile device, so using HLS (with it's larger chunk size) is impacting performance; this is why I would like to request the video be sent using DASH. [Here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-cloudflare-streams/), the Cloudflare team writes: "Cloudflare uses two standards for adaptive streaming: HLS and MPEG-DASH".

Every get request to the video has yielded a stream with HLS. Is there any way to request DASH given my Cloudflare video id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically a video origin server and CDN will serve the stream that best matches a devices capabilities - usually this triggered by the device requesting either a HLS or a MPEG DASH stream, the two most popular streaming format today.

Cloudflare Stream should provide you urls to both a HLS manifest and DASH manifest automatically - they should look something like:

> MPEG-DASH: https://videodelivery.net/VIDEOID/manifest/video.mpd
>
> HLS: https://videodelivery.net/VIDEOID/manifest/video.hls